# F# visual studio environment support

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, f#

I developing a small project with F# on Visual Studio 2012. I'm used to C# development, and it seems to me that C# has a far far (far) better support in the environment than F#, and even better support when adding resharper.

Are there any plugins that can improve that?
I would love snippets, better templates, code folding, refactoring, etc...

Is there is an open source project trying to achieve this?

Comment: Go over the add-in repository, there are some things. Snippets, code folding and (basic) refactoring are there (or at least were a year ago).

Comment: @RamonSnir I've looked there, it's not the level of support i would like to have :-)

Comment: No, it's not :) FSharpX is currently the most active OS project (maybe even the only one), but it concentrates on libraries more than on tools.

Comment: This is a good question to post to the [fsharp-opensource](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/fsharp-opensource) mailing list -- there are a number of people working on new tooling for F# or improving the F# support in existing tools.

Comment: I would also add that you should try to overlook the lack of tools until you are reasonably fluent. You may well find that some of the tooling you thought was essential actually becomes superfluous once you are writing idiomatic code.  I work on a large F# codebase and the only feature I really miss is refector -> rename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are fewer advanced code editing tools for F# than for C#. This is one thing where the F# community is quite active, so it is good idea to follow the mailing list and [fsharp.org web site](http://fsharp.org).

One less widely known thing is that the standard tooling includes (not very tested) support for collapsing of code blocks and navigation bar that [can be turned on](http://tomasp.net/blog/regions-navigation.aspx).